# According to google's matter example,How to export the fabric of the device, I want to bind the fabric to the account？

Tags: android, kotlin, google-home

I will develop my own matter application. If I want to save this fabric to my account after connecting to a matter device, what should I do?
What I want to achieve is: my account only needs to be bound to a device once, and I can get a legal fabric after logging in to the account with a different mobile phone.
I found compressedFabricId in Google's sample code, but it only has code for reconnection.

I want to connect directly after linking the account, does anyone know how to do it?